# How to perform matrix multiplication in R faster than %*%?

Tags: r, performance, matrix, matrix-multiplication

This problem occured in my R script. I want to multiply a 1000by1000 matrix by a 1000by1 matrix (vector), so that the output is a 1000by1 matrix.

The 1000by1000 matrix has a unique property. Above the diagonal there are only 0s.

The computation by %*% takes roughly 0.007 seconds, but its a bit slow.
I heared about sparse matrices, but its kind of a new thing.

Comment: Have you linked R against OpenBLAS?

Comment: Hi, I'm not really sure about it. Could you detail it a bit?

Comment: sessionInfo() will tell you. An optimized Basic Linear Algebra System offers better performance for matrix algebra than the default BLAS.

Comment: Matrix products: default
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Guess it's default then, what do you suggest?

Comment: Then I suggest linking against OpenBLAS. Instructions can be found in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can try `Rcpp` like below

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('NumericMatrix matmult0(const NumericMatrix& m1, const NumericMatrix& m2){
NumericMatrix out(m1.nrow(), 1);
NumericVector rm1, cm2;
for (size_t i = 0; i < m1.nrow(); ++i) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < i+1; ++j) {
        out(i,0) += m1(i,j)*m2(j,0);
    }
  }
return out;
}')
```

where you only need to have the multiplications and additions on non-zero entries of `m1`, due to the lower triangular feature.

---

Other `Rcpp` options might be using `RcppArmadillo`, e.g.,

```
sourceCpp(code = "
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace arma;
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
mat matmul1(const mat& A, const mat& B) {
    mat out(A.n_rows, 1, fill::zeros);
    for (uword i=0; i < A.n_rows; ++i) {
        out(i, 0) = dot(A.submat(i, 0, i, i), B.rows(0, i));
    }
    return out;
}
")
```

or

```
sourceCpp(code = "
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace arma;
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
mat matmul2(const mat& A, const mat& B) {
    return A*B;
}
")
```

## Benchmark

Given options like below

```
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppArmadillo)

cppFunction("NumericMatrix matmul0(const NumericMatrix& m1, const NumericMatrix& m2){
NumericMatrix out(m1.nrow(), 1);
NumericVector rm1, cm2;
for (size_t i = 0; i < m1.nrow(); ++i) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < i+1; ++j) {
        out(i,0) += m1(i,j)*m2(j,0);
    }
  }
return out;
}")

sourceCpp(code = "
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace arma;
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
mat matmul1(const mat& A, const mat& B) {
    mat out(A.n_rows, 1, fill::zeros);
    for (uword i=0; i < A.n_rows; ++i) {
        out(i, 0) = dot(A.submat(i, 0, i, i), B.rows(0, i));
    }
    return out;
}
")

sourceCpp(code = "
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace arma;
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
mat matmul2(const mat& A, const mat& B) {
    return A*B;
}
")


bm <- function(n) {
    set.seed(0)
    m1 <- matrix(runif(n^2), n, n)
    m1[upper.tri(m1)] <- 0
    v <- matrix(rnorm(n))

    microbenchmark(
        m1 %*% v,
        matmul0(m1, v),
        matmul1(m1, v),
        matmul2(m1, v),
        check = "equivalent",
        unit = "relative",
        times = 10L
    )
}
```

we run `A` of size `n-by-n` and `B` of size `n-by-1`

```
> bm(1e2)
Unit: relative
           expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq        max neval
       m1 %*% v 2.255289 2.107408 0.1554016 2.178938 2.326700 0.02751298    10
 matmul0(m1, v) 1.000000 1.000000 1.0000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.00000000    10
 matmul1(m1, v) 3.057545 3.548113 1.3826202 3.799905 4.534403 1.20854982    10
 matmul2(m1, v) 1.116136 1.053865 0.9667361 1.131625 1.148401 0.95306185    10

> bm(1e3)
Unit: relative
           expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
       m1 %*% v 2.062955 2.090966 2.064470 2.139800 2.019504 2.033714    10
 matmul0(m1, v) 1.204226 1.447327 1.399555 1.390832 1.325719 1.525917    10
 matmul1(m1, v) 2.450843 2.038131 2.018818 1.942346 1.859387 1.992065    10
 matmul2(m1, v) 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    10

> bm(1e4)
Unit: relative
           expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
       m1 %*% v 2.216098 2.271501 2.197276 2.238108 2.130116 2.122360    10
 matmul0(m1, v) 5.827486 5.912506 5.640343 5.814122 5.537054 5.092440    10
 matmul1(m1, v) 7.712787 7.842202 7.415922 7.700673 7.220260 6.561256    10
 matmul2(m1, v) 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    10
```

Comment: No, don’t implement matrix algebra yourself. Use the BLAS. If you want to use Rcpp, use Eigen or Armadillo.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for the recommendation. BTW, could you elaborate the reason of using Armadillo or Eigen? For speed or precision?

Comment: Yes, those are C++ libraries dedicated and optimized for matrix operations and algebra. RcppEigen and RcppArmadillo make using them quite convenient.

Comment: @Roland I did some benchmarking, interestingly `%*%` is faster than `Armadillo` for super large matrices, and my raw `Rcpp` seems not that bad as thought :P

Comment: R is passing the matrix multiplication to the BLAS. You are measuring overhead plus BLAS performance.

Comment: @Roland aha, now I see the point :) Thanks!

Comment: The proposed C++ code has an unnecessary performance bottleneck: the matrices are passed by value (i.e. copied) instead of more efficiently by reference (no copy). Change `mat matmul2(mat A, mat B)` to mat `matmul2(const mat& A, const mat& B)` to avoid the copy.  Note the `&` characters.

Comment: @mtall aha, yes, you are right! Now I learnt new things from you, thanks :)

Comment: @mtall BTW, is there any way to improve more about `matmul1`?

Comment: @mtall I don't think that's correct. Ultimately, the function arguments are SEXP objects, i.e. pointers.

Answer (score -1):

In order to get any sort of speed-up by using sparse matrices, you would need to create the lower triangular matrix originally as a sparse matrix. Conversion from a regular matrix to a sparse matrix is much slower than the multiplication:

```
library(Matrix)

m1 <- matrix(runif(1e6), 1e3, 1e3)
m1[upper.tri(m1)] <- 0
v <- rnorm(1e3)
m2 <- as(m1, "triangularMatrix")

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  m1 %*% v,
  m2 %*% v,
  as(m1, "triangularMatrix") %*% v
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                              expr      min        lq     mean    median        uq       max neval
#>                          m1 %*% v  787.301  829.8510  933.968  901.5515  982.0515  1562.900   100
#>                          m2 %*% v  194.501  241.1515  337.908  349.1005  394.7520  1252.501   100
#>  as(m1, "triangularMatrix") %*% v 2124.201 2235.6505 3974.169 2412.8510 2967.1505 96792.001   100
```

Comment: It helped, thank you for the answer!
This new "triangularMatrix" can be modified too? For example adding an other (normal) matrix to it which matches its number of columns and rows, and also has 0s above the diagonal, but has not been modified by the as() function?

Comment: Yes. Say `m3` were a regular 1000 x 1000 lower triangular matrix, then you could do `m2 + m3`. Also, for the result of the multiplication, the vector of values can be obtained with `@x` (e.g., `(m2 %*% v)@x`).

Comment: Although, I admit I'm having a hard time envisioning a process where a 7 ms matrix multiplication is the bottleneck. Does it happen inside an optimizer or root finder?

Comment: Its more like an optimisitaion. The whole function has to run a couple houndred times, so it adds up a bit. If you are interested, I can show a bit more about it.

Comment: It's probably out of scope for this question. But if you have working code, you might try [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Let me know if you do, and I'll take a look.